# php call function from another class

Tags: php, ajax, function, jquery-mobile

I am trying to call a function with arguments from another class.  The class with the function I need to call is ***auth.class.php*** (it's pretty long so I've shorten to the relevant class). I've a ***index.php*** file with jQuery form that when post calls ***reg.php*** and sends data their. I want to call the register function in ***auth.class.php*** file from the reg.php

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I think the ajax might be the problem but any help will be appreciated.

auth.class.php

```
 <?php
class Auth {

 public function register($email, $username, $password, $repeatpassword)
{
    $return = array();
    $return['code'] = 400;

    if ($this->isBlocked()) {
        $return['code'] = 0;
        return $return;
    } else {
        $validateEmail = $this->validateEmail($email);
        $validateUsername = $this->validateUsername($username);
        $validatePassword = $this->validatePassword($password);

        if ($validateEmail['error'] == 1) {
            $return['message'] = $validateEmail['message'];
            return $return;
        } elseif ($validateUsername['error'] == 1) {
            $return['message'] = $validateUsername['message'];
            return $return;
        } elseif ($validatePassword['error'] == 1) {
            $return['message'] = $validatePassword['message'];
            return $return;
        } elseif($password !== $repeatpassword) {
            $return['message'] = "password_nomatch";
            return $return;
        } else {
            if (!$this->isEmailTaken($email)) {
                if (!$this->isUsernameTaken($username)) {
                    $addUser = $this->addUser($email, $username, $password);

                    if($addUser['error'] == 0) {
                        $return['code'] = 200;
                        $return['message'] = "register_success";
                        return $return;
                    } else {
                        $return['message'] = $addUser['message'];
                        return $return;
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->addAttempt();

                    $this->addNewLog("", "REGISTER_FAIL_USERNAME", "User attempted to register new account with the username : {$username} -> Username already in use");

                    $return['message'] = "username_taken";
                    return $return;
                }
            } else {
                $this->addAttempt();

                $this->addNewLog("", "REGISTER_FAIL_EMAIL", "User attempted to register new account with the email : {$email} -> Email already in use");

                $return['message'] = "email_taken";
                return $return;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my html file  **index.php** I am using jQuery mobile with ajax

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Submit a form via AJAX
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function onSuccess(data, status)
            {
                data = $.trim(data);
                $("#notification").text(data);
            }

            function onError(data, status)
            {
                // handle an error
            }

            $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $("#submit").click(function()
                        {

                            var formData = $("#Register").serialize();

                            $.ajax(
                                {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "reg.php",
                                    cache: false,
                                    data: formData,
                                    success: onSuccess,
                                    error: onError
                                });

                            return false;
                        });
                });
        </script>

        <!-- call ajax page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="callAjaxPage">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>
                    Call Ajax
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <form id="Register">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="Email">
                            eMail
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
                        <br />
                        <label for="UserName">
                            User Name
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""  />
                        <br />

                        <label for="Password">
                            Password
                        </label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""  />
                        <br />
                        <label for="Confirmpassword">
                            Confirm Password
                        </label>
                        <input type="password" name="repeatpassword" id="repeatpassword" value=""  />

                        <h3 id="notification">
                        </h3>
                        <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h1>
                    GiantFlyingSaucer
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my the php file that's placing the call the auth.class.php function.

```
<?php

include_once "password.php";
require_once "auth.class.php";

$mail     = $_POST[email];
$usn      = $_POST[username];
$pswd     = $_POST[password];
$cpswd    = $_POST[repeatpassword];

$register = new Auth();
$register ->register($mail, $usn, $pswd, $cpswd);

echo $return;
?>
```

Comment: `echo $return;` ? `echo $register->register($mail, $usn, $pswd, $cpswd);` Maybe, following you error...

Comment: What is your question, error, current output, desired behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Make index.php all the code is here and ajax function also here and make calls.php which is call by ajax function and calls.php file call your class.auth.php file.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't assign the value returned by your function to anything.

Try this:

```
  $return= $register ->register($mail, $usn, $pswd, $cpswd);
  echo $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code that fixed the problem. I wasn't passing the data as an array serializeArray and also made some changes in the reg.php class as well.

New ***index.php*** file

```
  <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mobile: Theme Download</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Carelincs.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

            $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $("#submit").click(function()
                        {

                            var formData = $("#register").serializeArray();

                            $.ajax(
                                {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "../pages/register.php",
                                    cache: false,
                                    data: formData,
                                    success: onSuccess,

                                });

                            return false;
                        });
                }); 


                function onSuccess(data, status)
            {

                data = $.trim(data);
                $("#message").text(data);
            }

            function onError(data, status)
            {
                //Handle error
            }

</script>



    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            <form action="" method="POST" id="register">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="eMail"/>
                <br />
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name"/>
                <br />
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                <br />
                <label for="confirm password">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="repeatpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                <br />
                <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <p id="message"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

new ***reg.php*** file I also added information to connect to database.

```
<?php


require_once("../auth/config.class.php");
require_once("../auth/auth.class.php");

$config = new Config;

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $config-> dbhost . ";dbname=" . $config->dbname,  $config->dbuser, $config->dbpass);


$auth = new Auth($dbh, $config);



$email = $_POST["email"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$repeatpassword = $_POST["repeatpassword"];


$register = $auth->register($email, $username, $password, $repeatpassword ); 

// Temporary just to see what's going on :
var_dump($register);

?>
```